# Can't activate Windows 7 Professional Online?

Tags: windows-7

When i'm trying to activate my Windows 7 Professional in online i've got error like this -

```
A problem occurred when Windows tried to activate. Error code 0x8007007B. For a possible resolution, click MoreInformation.

Contact your system administrator or technial support department for assistance.

More Information - 

The following information was found for this error :

code : 
  0x8007007B

Description :
   The filename, directory name, or volume lable syntax is incorrect.
```

What can i do for this? My another pc didn't raise this error. It's activated perfectly.

Comment: did you use the 'same' version of Win7 on the *other* pc? ;)

Comment: See if this helps: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/accaccad-94db-40c6-b0e2-1be2ceec8883  (googling the exact error message coughed it up; that's often useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having problems activating online you can simply telephone Microsoft and activate over the phone.

Comment: and when it asks `On how many computers is this version of Microsoft Windows installed on` you will be honest and press `1` ...

Comment: @ppumkin: I took his question at face value. He didn't ask "How can I bootleg Windows onto multiple computers?"

Comment: I know.. I did write the comment did I not? :-]

Comment: How to find a phone number for a Microsoft Product Activation Center
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950929